# locale parameter changes his location in link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, hyperlink

I have some serius problem, I created multiple language selection that works great, but the link is changing all the time.
From `http://localhost:3000/en/products` when I click such link

```
<%= link_to image_tag('en.png',:alt => 'description', :title =>  (I18n.t 'english') ), params.merge(:locale => :en) %>
```

To something like this after some time I am navigating inside app and clicking different links

```
http://localhost:3000/manufacturer_products?locale=en&manufacturer=Christophel
```

I believe that the problem is inside the routes.rb file.

This is my **routes file**.

```
 root :to => 'home#index'
    devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  get "about_us/index"

namespace :products do
  resources :categories do
    resources :products
  end

  resources :products, only: :index
end

namespace :products do
  resources :manufacturs do
    resources :products
  end

  resources :products, only: :index
end
  get "about/index"
  match ":locale/products/search" => "products#search"
  match "/contacts", to: "contacts#index"
  match "/products", to: "products#index"
  match "/home", to: "home#index"
  match "/about_us", to: "about_us#index"
  match "/news", to: "news#index"
  match "/manufacturer_products", to: "manufacturer_products#index"

match '/:locale' => 'home#index'
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|lv|ru/ do
 resources :products, :manufacturers, :categories, :news, :ActiveAdmin, :manufacturer_products

end
```

I understand that I have to somehow merge namespace:products route with locale route, but I have no idea to start with, If somebody could give me a tip or smth :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, the thing was that in routes file I didn't have right order of the routes. 
This route that handles routing with locales I had at the end off file. So it didn't work.

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|lv|ru/ do
   resources :products, :manufacturers, :categories, :news, :ActiveAdmin, :manufacturer_products, :about_us, :contacts
end
```

I moved this code to begining of the file and now it works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your routes are not a problem.

params.merge(:locale => :lv) has the function of joining 2 hashes, so you should just use something like

params[:locale] || :en

Comment: Not working this solution, it redirects to root page after clicking it and after clicking other links it changes the locale location from begining of link to end.

Comment: so use this: `params.keep_if{|k, v| ['locale', 'controller', 'action'].include? k}`. This means that you keep as parameters of link to only the 3 parameters your really need: controller, action and locale

Comment: The same, nothing changed.

Comment: I need to keep that locale parameter, but in constant place. `www.mysite.com/en/products` for example, but now it keeps changing that place to end of the link.